# Close iFrame from another webpage + asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iframe, dialog

I am working on a ASP.NET Web application. I have two web pages, Web Page 1 has iFrame in which Web Page 2 is loaded using jQuery dialog.

From web page 1 when clicked a hyper link, iframe will be loaded with second webpage, Some operations are perfromed on webpage 2 (submitting data to db), after submitting data hitting submit button, want to close the Iframe/Dialog so that user will be redirected to Web Page 1.

How can I close the IFrame/Dialog which is in Web Page 1 from Web Page 2 ??

It's asp.net webforms application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried in this way and it worked:

In webpage 1 wrote a function which closes/removed iframe:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">
var removeMyIFrame = function() {
     $('#MyiFrame').remove();
}
   </script>
```

called above function from secodnd page using below snippet:

ASPX:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">
        function CloseMe() {
            parent.removeMyIFrame()
        }
   </script>
```

.CS Button click :

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Page.[GetType](), "text", "CloseMe()", True)
```